# Server is resolving to some strange DNS

Tags: dns

This is not a C# question. This has to do more with our servers. Basically we've been noticing that another DNS address is resolving to our server's address, example.

Our DNS: www.bob.com

The other mysterious DNS that resolves to our IP: thing.blah8.com

This is actually a rather serious issue because some how this random DNS is being picked up by google and people are reaching our website through this address. So anyone have any ideas where this second DNS address is coming from? Anyone seen this strange behavior before? I'm guessing it might be the name of the box of our webhost.

Any hints or tips of where to look would be great. As a note, we've already checked our DNS server and there is no obvious clue as to where that address is coming from.

Comment: thing.bum8.com does not resolve anywhere for me and I don't see any correlation between bum8.com and bob.com. maybe your DNS server has been compromised or there's something else going on locally?

Comment: It was just an example. I can't obviously disclose which website is having this issue lol

Comment: [Don't be silly.  Of course you can.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html)  You already have. **You are already publishing this information to the world with your DNS servers.**  Your question is "Why does domain name X map to IP address Y?" without telling anyone what X and Y are.  If you don't provide names, there's no way for the rest of us to find out for you _where_ and _why_ the mapping is published.  We aren't clairvoyant.  At best you are going to get guesses from people.

Comment: You're right... In the end however the server was killed. So not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try contacting their technical domain contact (get it through a WHOIS request) and let them know their DNS is wrong. There's nothing you could forcefully do to stop them, outside of catching this hostname request with your web server and serving those visitors a different page. Some might say traffic is traffic, but I assume you don't agree. :)

It doesn't have anything to do with your servers, it's the remote sites DNS zone that is configured with your IP address.  You couldn't make that happen.